# How to programmatically set a file in "hidden" in C

Tags: c, windows, file, hide

I'am working on an program in C for a web connected touchscreen.

In case internet is down, my boss want me to write in a low secured file the intels about the sales, for memory when internet will be back.

For now, its on a `.txt`, and I'd like to set the attribute of the file in "hidden".

One of you got a function or an open flag for that case?

The OS I am using is Windows 7.

Comment: [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to the operation system.
When you create a file you can pass a couple of attributes describing the file.
In case of windows you have : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN.
If you already have a file you can call the SetFileAttributes function.Check this link from msdn :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can use `SetFileAttributes()` function described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx)